# Firebase Phone Login on iOS

Tags: swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication, twitter-digits

Since Digits are baked into Firebase. We're now forced to use Firebase to implement SMS login, however, when setting up Firebase Phone login

The Firebase documentation says

> To use phone number authentication, your app must be able to receive
>   APNs notifications from Firebase. When you sign in a user with their
>   phone number for the first time on a device, Firebase Authentication
>   sends a silent push notification to the device to verify that the
>   phone number sign-in request comes from your app. (For this reason,
>   phone number sign-in cannot be used on a simulator.)

I am wondering if it is possible to skip this part? Because we are using OneSignal as our Push Notification framework.

Any ideas?

Comment: I din't know about OneSignal, but did u implement didReceiveRemoteNotification method in AppDelegate?

Comment: @hamentmiglani yes, OneSignal uses that method too

Comment: then u can implement Firebase authentication without swizzling methods!
from this link
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth